# How to stop material-mkdocs from trimming inlineCodeBlock whitespace?

Tags: mkdocs

(material-)mkdocs trims all whitespace from inline codeblocks like this one: `:`  so the result looks like this `:`.

I tried to specify a language using a shebang - as i though that this might be a dirty workaround - but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround! It's possible to use the `braille blank` character. You can copy it on this site: https://qwerty.dev/whitespace/